# Load or convert varbinary from sql to textbox text?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm new one in C# programming.
At present I try to save and load a text file to sql server. I watched and searched some videos and document on youtube. They stored image file to sql. I try and already saved the text file to server (binary data). Now I stuck how to load or convert it:

When I save it, I used memorystream:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textreview.Text);
byte[] theBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textreview.Text);
ms.Position = 0;
ms.Read(theBytes, 0, theBytes.Length);

//insert value to server
SqlCommand cmdb = new SqlCommand("insert into Assignment(text) values (@text)", con);
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textname", textPathLabel.Text);
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", theBytes);
```

Now I try to load it but I stuck here!

```
//load from sql
byte[] picarr = (byte[])dr["text"];
ms = new MemoryStream(picarr);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
textreview.Text = text;
```

Comment: So, what's the concrete problem?

Comment: i load it into a textbox text. but it have no result! :(

Comment: Why don't you just store the result from `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textreview.Text)`?

Comment: +1 for a newbie that actually uses `SQLParameters`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example on how you convert a text to bytes and then back again:

`var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test");`

This will give you a byte array that looks like this:

`{ 116, 101, 115, 116 }`

Now to get the text again, you can use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` like this:

`Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);`

This means that you could simple do this when saving the value:

`cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textreview.Text));`

And then when loading it back you simply do this:

`textreview.Text = Encoding.GetString((byte[])dr["text"]);`